# Power Query - complicated custom column

Tags: excel, if-statement, powerquery, m, customcolumn

I need to create a custom column which looks at 1 column, `a`, and based on `a`, trims a value from `b` and puts the value in `c`.

Part B: Now if the value in `a` does not match my criteria, then it looks at column `d` to find if it was the same as the previous row and if yes then puts the value of `c` from the previous row into the new row.

I have one part of it now:

```
if Text.End ([SAP segment name],3) = "K09"
then Text.Trim (Text.Start([Application data],35)) else ""
```

I need help with Part B

Answer (score 0):

Your formula [B3=IF(RIGHT(R3,3)="K09",TRIM(LEFT(W3,35)), B2) ] will return an error for every row until the first time R ends in K09.  However if that's what you want then

```
let Source = Table.FromList({
[SAP segment name="L04K29", Application data ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP12345VWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"] ,  
[SAP segment name="R03L09", Application data ="abcdefghijklmnop67890qrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"] ,  
[SAP segment name="L04K09", Application data ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP987654QRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"] ,  
[SAP segment name="L04K09", Application data ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR321254STUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"] ,  
[SAP segment name="R03G09", Application data ="abcdefghijklmnopqrst87562uvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"] ,  
[SAP segment name="L04K09", Application data ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU45265VWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"] 
}, Record.FieldValues, {"SAP segment name", "Application data"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if Text.End ([SAP segment name],3) = "K09" then Text.Trim(Text.Start([Application data],35)) else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"})
in
#"Filled Down"
```

Comment: I am getting errors:Expression.Error: The name 'PreviousStep' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Comment: because you were supposed to use the name of your previous step, not literally use the text "PreviousStep"

Comment: I am trying to convert excel this formula into a power query formula: B3=IF(RIGHT(R3,3)="K09",TRIM(LEFT(W3,35)), B2)

Comment: I did understand the error and correct it, but it doesn't do what I wanted it to

Comment: changed answer above

Comment: This is what I have right now.                                                                     =if [#"Segment No."] = 1 then 
Text.Trim (Text.Start([Application data],35)) 
else {[Index]}{[PO Number]}............................................. but It is having trouble getting the previous row's value for PO Number